# Pass a list between screens. Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using Visual Studio 15 and started creating an app for windows phone 8.1
So at this point i need to check all checked checkboxes and pick his text and add checked values to a List (This already did) now, i need to pass this list between pages, i'm stuck, i know only winforms way, and it's not work

Here de the code of page 1

```
        CheckBox[] checkboxes = new CheckBox[] { checkBox, checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6,checkBox7,checkBox8,checkBox9, checkbox10, checkbox11, checkbox12, checkbox13};

        List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();
        ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();

        foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
        {
            if (c.IsChecked == true)
            {                  
                cDados.Pedido = c.Content.ToString();
                lista.Add(cDados);
            }
        }

        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Carrinho), (cDados));
```

Now the code on second page

```
public sealed partial class Carrinho : Page
{
    List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();

    public <here>Carrinho</here>(List<ClassDados> cDados)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        lista = cDados;
    }...
```

My Class

```
class ClassDados
{
    public string Pedido { get; set; }
    public int Valor { get; set; }
```

"Here" on second page im getting the error: Error   CS0051  Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'List' is less accessible than method 'Carrinho.Carrinho(List)'

On windows forms C# i've used this way so much, but on WP it's not working, so can anyone tell me the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @Master117 not yet... same error... nothing changed :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(dest_page), parameter);
```

Just serializes `parameter` and pass it along to your dest_page, it doesn't call the constructor like you are assuming.

To get `parameter` you want to override the `OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)` of the second page like so:

```
public sealed partial class Carrinho : Page
{
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        YOUR_CLASS c = e.Parameter as YOUR_CLASS;
    }
}
```

Make sure the object you're passing is serializable (just keep it simple, and it will be okay).

---

Another way you can do this is to have a Global Resource Locator.  You can search SO for how to do this.  So basically, it's just a resource and you can reference it on any page you like.

Comment: Hm, I understand it. but now, i need the data sent to "cDados" on page 1 to show on page 2 on a richtextbox or other control. But i don't understand how i will do this with this code. Any help?

Comment: @Bazz you can either go through the list and add it in manually, or if your control has a ItemSource Property  then you can set the ItemSource = page2_list.  If you need more help, open a new question. If I asked your original question, mark it as solved.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you want

`foreach (CheckBox c in checkboxes)
        {
            ClassDados cDados = new ClassDados();
            if (c.IsChecked == true)
            {

                cDados.Pedido = c.Content.ToString();
                lista.Add(cDados);
            }
        }`

or you will only change the value of the same Dados.

2. You need to make List public on the second page:

   ```
   public List<ClassDados> lista = new List<ClassDados>();
   ```